# Postgresql parse url parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, parsing, url

The following is how I currently parse parameters from an url query string. Does anyone know of a nicer and faster solution? Thx.

```
select
  id,
  url,
  split_part(regexp_split_to_table((regexp_matches(url, '\?(.*)'))[1], '&'), '=', 1) as key,
  split_part(regexp_split_to_table((regexp_matches(url, '\?(.*)'))[1], '&'), '=', 2) as value
from ad;
```

Comment: did you have index for timestamp? Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: At the moment around 1.75M rows only, but it will fill quickly to tens or hundreds of millions.

Oops I didn't realise I pasted it with the order by and limit rows, didn't mean to, sorry. I edited the question to include only the neccessary things.

Comment: Still without the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` we cant know where is the slow part of the process.

Comment: So a `FULL SCAN` on 1.75 M rows? How fast you expect that be?

Answer (score 1):

You do two regexp matches for the same URL, and then two splits of the result.

I'd suggest using a simpler function to find the position of the first `?` in the URL, e.g. `substring(url, position('?' in url))`, then you likely can use `regexp_split_to_array` to do the splitting only once.

This can happen in a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) or a subquery; then you can access the array results by index to return.

This, of course, only makes sense if the query is dominated by the processing time, and not filtering and fetching time. *Optimization without profiling is a waste of time.*